# Laravel lumen get data from another relation

Tags: laravel, lumen

I have 3 tables `faculties`, `students`, `program_studies`. I'm using Lumen 5.7

Here is the tables:

faculties table:

```
-----------------
|id|faculty_name|
-----------------
| 1| test       |
-----------------
```

students table:

```
----------------------------------
|id|student_name|program_study_id|
----------------------------------
| 1| student 1  |               1|
----------------------------------
| 2| student 2  |               1|
----------------------------------
```

program_studies table:

```
----------------------------------
|id|program_study_name|faculty_id|
----------------------------------
| 1| program study    |         1|
----------------------------------
```

This is the model:

Student.php

```
public function programStudy()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ProgramStudy::class);
}
```

PorgramStudy.php

```
public function faculty()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Faculty::class);
}
```

Faculty.php

```
nothing relation in faculty model
```

How to get faculty data with relation in Student model ?

For now I'm create function like this in Student.php:

```
public function getFaculty()
{
    return $this->programStudy()->first()->faculty()->first();
}
```

but I want to get faculty data using relation not function, if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`hasOneThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through) relationship to link your Student to a Faculty.

```php
public function faculty()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(Faculty::class, ProgramStudy::class);
}
```

Comment: I'm already try use hasOneThrough but get this error

`"Call to undefined method App\\Models\\Student::hasOneThrough()"`

if i call `dd($student->faculty);` in StudentController

Comment: Does your Student model actually extend `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, or are you using an older version of Laravel?

Comment: I'm already add `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;` , I'm using Lumen 5.7

Comment: Apologies - it looks like `hasOneThrough` was introduced in Laravel 5.8. You'll likely want to update your Lumen installation if possible.